# The volume of body in polar coordinates

Tags: integration, volume

If we have curve $r=F(\varphi)$ and two polar radii $\varphi=\alpha$ and $\varphi=\beta$ $(\alpha<\beta)$. Then volume of body which is bounded by above polar curve and lines which is revolved around polar axis is equal to the following integral: $$\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\int \limits_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^3\sin \varphi \ d\varphi$$

This is from my calculus Russian book. How to derive that formula?

Can anyone please show it?

Comment: It appears in the formula because $r=F(\varphi)$

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a body in spherical coordinates is given by

$$V=\int_V dV=\int_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2}\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}r^2\sin\varphi~dr~d\theta~d\varphi$$

Now, if $r=r(\varphi)$ only and it is a body of revolution, i.e. $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, then

$$
\begin{align}
V
&=2\pi~\int_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}r^2\sin\varphi~dr~d\varphi\\
&=2\pi~\int_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2}\frac{r^3}{3}\sin\varphi~d\varphi\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3}~\int_{\varphi_1}^{\varphi_2}r^3\sin\varphi~d\varphi\\
\end{align}
$$

as expected.

Comment: It's great but here you have used double integrals. I would like to see at proof without it.

Comment: @RFZ: You are essentially computing an area, ultimately it reduces to a double integral?

Comment: @RFZ Somewhere along the line you have to use a double integral. I was looking for Pappus's centroid theorem in polar or spherical coordinates (no luck). But even there, you need an area and centroid, both of which are double integrals. I don't know what you want. There's no magic here; volume requires a triple integral to start with, no matter what. The object in many such problems is to reduce the number of integrations where possible. I've shown how to do that.

Comment: @RFZ See my new post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2456078/what-is-the-volume-of-a-body-of-revolution-in-polar-coordinates.